# How to initialize private variable in class in c++?

Tags: c++, class

Error is: **data member initializer is not allow**
How to initialize private variable in class in c++?

```
class CreditCard 
{
public:
    CreditCard();
    CreditCard(int bc);

    double getCredLimit();
    double getBalDue();
    int getAccNum();
    double credAvailable();
    int incre_Credit();
    void trans1();
    int cdInc();
    bool addingChrg(double chrgAmt, const std::string& desc);

    ~CreditCard();

private:
    int accNo;
    bool err;
    string mssg;
    double dueAmt;

    void wtStats();
    void logFl(string qu);
    string credName, credlastName;
    double lim;
    double bala = lim;     //Here i getting error how to solve this
    double payscale;
    double chrg;
};
```

how to intialize private varable in class in c++;
and thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you expect `bala` to contain, as your `lim` is not initialized?

Comment: Error is: data member initializer is not allow

Comment: I am not asking what the error is, I am asking what do you expect it to behave.  What you are doing now does not make sense

Comment: lim is double and bala is double how to give lim to bala in class??

Comment: your `lim` is not initialized with any meaningful value, and you are initializing `bala` with this uninitialized value.  What is the purpose doing so?

Comment: so how i initalize lim in class

Comment: So, be specific and clear on your question: do you want to know what is the proper way to initialize member variables, or do you want to know how to initialize a member variable using another member variable?  Make your example short and concise, without containing irrelevant information please.  A quick search with "C++ initialize member variable" should give you plenty of information though

Answer (score 4):

`bala` is being initialized to `lim`, but `lim` is not initialized. You need to initialize `lim' too. For example:

```
double lim = 0.0;
double bala = lim;
```

You should initialize all your members though. Currently, you don't seem to initialize any of them.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize it within a constructor:

```
class CreditCard 
{
public:
    CreditCard() {
        lim = -1;
        bala = lim;
    }
    // rest of code
};
```

Comment: Technically speaking, this is not *initialization*

Comment: If you are going to add initialization of `lim` anyway (`lim = -1;` ), you do not really need to do it in constructor.

Comment: And if you *are* going to do it in a constructor  you should do it properly: `CreditCard() : lim(-1), bala(lim) {}`.

Comment: @user207421 that is an opinion-based preference. You can either do it inside the constructor or using an initialization-list. Either way works fine. For Java-users who also work with C++ the former is more preferable and readable.